# Using sed to replace string with a variable

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I am new to sed and I want to do some string manipulation. I have a string

```
 el2="action:json:{"command":"submit","sessionId":1,"data":{"ELEMENT":":wdc:dscdcd"}}"
```

and I have a variable el1="ELEMENT":":wdc:1372054342282". I want to new el2 to become:

```
 el2="action:json:{"command":"submit","sessionId":1,"data":{"ELEMENT":":wdc:1372054342282"}}"
```

How can I accomplish this with sed?

Comment: why not using a scripting language which has json support? python, perl, php coming in mind... while it is possible to solve almost every editing problem - even yours - , sed is not really meant for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `sed` needed, parameter expansion is enough:

```
el2=${el2/'"ELEMENT":'*'}}'/"$el1}}"}
```

Using Perl with its [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) library would be safer, though.

```
use JSON;
$s = '"action:json:{"command":"submit","sessionId":1,"data":{"ELEMENT":":wdc:dscdcd"}}"';
$s =~ s/"action:json://;
$s =~ s/"$//;
$j = decode_json($s);
$j->{data}{ELEMENT} = ':wdc:1372054342282';
print '"action:json:', encode_json($j), '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
el2=$(echo "$el2" | sed 's/"ELEMENT[^}]*"/'"$el1/")
```